# How to pass array from library in c

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing, libraries

I'm new in c programming and I want to pass array from library.
I have function in library c file that creates char array. How to use this array in main function. This is short code of something I tried:

libfile.c

```
char *myArray;
void PopulateArray()
{
  // Getting data from serial port in char buffer[100]
  myArray = buffer;
}
```

libfile.h

```
exter char *myArray;
void PopulateArray();
```

program.c

```
int main()
{
   // in fore loop
  printf("%s\n" , myArray[i]);
}
```

This is just one of combinations that I have tried but nothing works.
How to do this?

Comment: Is this library statically or dynamically linked to your project?

Comment: Have you included the necessary headers

Comment: It's statically connected. But if there is difference it would be good  to know both :D

Comment: Yes I have. In this particular case that I have shown It displays error. If I use printf("%i", myArray[i]) it works but shows wrong data.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a minimal working example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines). The code you posted isn't complete, so it's hard to see what you're doing (for instance: how do you populate the array? What's the form of the for loop in the main() function?)

Comment: I populate array from serial port using: `open(file_desc, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` and get array of data that I wont to read as hexadecimal values in main function. But that is not relevant, I just want to know how to use char array created in file1.c in file2.c. I can do this with variables but not with arrays

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array from a library function to the surrounding code, you can use the return value of a function or use a pointer-to-pointer argument.

See the following example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* createSourceCopy() {
    const char *source = "Example Text";
    // We got some text in variable source;
    const size_t sourceSize = strlen(source);
    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(sourceSize+1));
    strncpy(result, source, sourceSize);
    return result;
}
```

A user of your library could use the function like this:

```
main() {
    char *result = createSourceCopy();
    // Do something with result.
    // After the use, destroy the array
    delete[] result;
    return 0;
}
```

Another way how to pass an array is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool copySourceText( char **outText ) {
    const char *source = "Example Text";
    // We get some text in variable source;
    const size_t sourceSize = strlen(source);
    *outText = new char[sourceSize];
    strncpy(*outText, source, sourceSize);
    return true; // success
}
```

This second variant has the benefit that the return value can be used as status. The function could return `true` on success, or `false` if there was an error.

This second version can be used like this.

```
int main() {
    char *result;
    if (copySourceText(&result)) {
        // Do something with result.
        // After the use, destroy the array
        free(result);
        result = NULL;
    } else {
        // Error handling
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` and `delete[]` are not plain C as the question is tagged. Would be convenient if you could use the C equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what's going wrong in the code you posted (it would help to see more code), but assuming your problem isn't a compilation error, one of these lines might be wrong:

```
char *myArray;
printf("%s\n" , myArray[i]);
```

- `char *myArray` declares a pointer to char (which would be appropriate for a single string).
- The `printf` line dereferences `myArray` (producing a `char`, i.e. one character). You're passing down a `char`, but the `%s` format expects a pointer-to-`char`.

If you want to print the string character-by-character, you could use `%c`:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", myArray[i]);   /* or %x or %d if you want */
}
```

Otherwise, if `myArray` is one string and is null-terminated (see [Why is a null terminator necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371157/why-is-a-null-terminator-necessary)), then you could do:

```
printf("%s\n" , myArray);   /* [i] removed, no for loop necessary */
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't solve my problem. I have buffer with some characters `buffer[100] = { 0x2, 0x17, 0x20 etc.. }` and I wish to access each of these characters individually. buffer is populated with data in function in libfile.c and I want to read these data in function in program.c